# Increasing binary search for mismatch in sorted range

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, stl, binary-search

**Update**

After fixing some defects in code below the question was reworked and posted as Code Review Request [Incremental upper bound in sorted range](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289146/incremental-upper-bound-in-sorted-range).

**Original question**

I have very large vector (gigabytes) with repeated sorted values and often need to jump to the next different value in the vector. Actual values in the vector are not integers and comparison is time-consuming operation, so using [`std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) is not effective here, since it involves about log2(n) comparisons while the needed element is often very close (about 1-10, very rarely 11-100 elements far from current and quite rare more than 101).

I found that in my case **increasing** binary search is faster (about 30% faster) than `std::upper_bound` for full vector.

With this I feel like reinventing the bicycle. For sure, I not a first person who invented this algorithm. Is there something in STL which could be used as the ready solution?

And the related question: is this code correct or I missing some traps; is any kind of improvement yet possible?

Here is the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GrT4Tn7Pv):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template<class ForwardIt, class Comp = std::less<>>
constexpr ForwardIt increasingMismatchBinarySearch(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Comp comp = {}, size_t starting_search_range = 1)
{
    const auto current = *first++;

    size_t short_search_range = starting_search_range;

    while (first != last) {
        const auto short_search_end = std::min(first + short_search_range, last);

        first = std::upper_bound(first, short_search_end, current, comp);

        if (first != short_search_end)
            return first;

        short_search_range *= 2;
    }

    return last;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7 };

    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it = increasingMismatchBinarySearch(it, v.end())) {
        // Some work
    }
}
```

Comment: I see nothing in the C++ library for this. This looks like a highly specialized, boutique, situation. Algorithms in the C++ library tend to be generic, simple, basic algorithms.

Comment: You might consider storing your data as sorted (value, repeat_count) pairs, instead of having duplicates in the vector.

Comment: @Damir Tenishev This statement const auto current = *first++; already can invoke undefined behavior.:)

Comment: It would be worth generating a histogram of the number of repeats in the vector as a function of run length to fine tune your search algorithm. Initial stride of 4 might be a better starting point from what you have described. BTW I prefer @BenVoigt suggestion to hold your data as values and repeat count pair. Then next distinct value is easy.

Comment: @Damir Tenishev Forward iterators do not have the operation + used in this expression first + short_search_range.:) And moreover even for random access iterators this expression std::min(first + short_search_range, last) again can invoke undefined behavior.:)

Comment: @BenVoigt, yes I have such a version, but it requires additional size_t variable for *repeat_count* and when it comes to gigabytes of data, this becomes memory-bound and works slower (measured on real data); additionally this requires calculation of this repeat_count while it depends on predicate (how I compare values) and could force to have many such values for every predicate. Works of simple cases, doesn't work in complex ones.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, could you please give a clue why `auto current = *first++;` could invoke undefined behaviour? I don't see the risks here.

Comment: @MartinBrown, this is what I've really done on real data. Mostly is has exponential dependency: I have only one item of this value in 50% of cases, two items in 25% of cases and 3 items in 12.5% of cases and so on. Of course, on average. I found this binary increasing solution fastest from everything I tried.

Comment: @DamirTenishev We, beginners, are always glad to help Mentors, Architects, Lead Developers, Project Managers, Product Managers, Team Leads and so on. For all algorithms at least till now the user can pass an empty range.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, thank for the catch, actually for the moment I use them for random access iterators, but I am not sure I should limit algorithm to them only because of this operations. For example, `std::upper_bound` works for forward iterators using `std::advance(it, step);`. I am looking now for a way to rewrite my code in this manner. The `std::min` could be more tricky, meanwhile. Any advice how to handle this better?

Comment: @DamirTenishev Before using this expression you can take into account the distance: std::distance( first, last )

Comment: @DamirTenishev: If you don't have random-access iterators, you're going to need a linear scan, and `upper_bound` already does that.  So no need for your wrapper.

Comment: You could write a `bounded_advance(begin, end, step_count)` abstraction and implement it for both random access iterators (use `std::min(step_count, end-begin)` to avoid wild iterator arithmetic) and forward iterators (increment in a loop with two termination conditions -- reaching `step_count` or reaching `end`).  Then your function doesn't need to care which happens.

Comment: Note that `std::ranges::advance` already provides an overload to perform a bounded advance: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ranges/advance but requires C++20

Comment: @BenVoigt, thank you, it helps. For the moment I decided to stay with random access iterators to keep things simple since I use random access containers only at the moment. Will follow in case I cover others.

Comment: @BenVoigt, on the `std::ranges::advance`. Is it fine to use ranges inside implementation like mine which is intended to work with pure STL iterators or this could involve extra expenses on conversions which I want to avoid?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, ( call of duty (aka ex officio) :) ; the nice thing about SO is that people here don't envy project roles and give them chance to ask, learn and answer to them. :) ). Nice catch on empty range, thank you. Focusing on "different than current" I assumed that current element should exist and range couldn't be empty. Of course, this was a trap. Fixed. I decided to stay with random access iterators to keep code simple, since I use this algorithm with random access containers only. I posted the updated version of the code as an answer. Could you please, revisit if it is fine now?

Comment: Is it a typo that the `Comp` template parameter doesn't match the `comp` used in `upper_bound`?

Comment: Have you compared this to a simple linear search using `std::equal` instead of `std::less`?  You say your comparison function is complex so it might be simpler and faster, no way to know without benchmarking.

Comment: @MarkRansom, `Comp` is a type name, `comp` is a variable name. Am I wrong somehow here?

Comment: Oops, sorry,  I didn't see your `comp` variable hiding in the parameter list, I needed to scroll right to see it.

Comment: @MarkRansom, is my actual code I use indexed text and std::less predicate provides lexicographical compare of sequence of identifiers (lexem ids), so `std::equal` here gives the same performance, since both actually comes to std::ranges::lexicographical_compare which is very close from performance standpoint to std::ranges:mismatch. Anyway, thank you, I will double check on real data.

Comment: @DamirTenishev I can advice to delete this question and ask a new question with your updated code. Also the function can be named something like incremetal_upper_bound.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, do you mean that the code still needs fixes and improvements and a new question should work for this? I posted the code as an answer, couldn't this work? I like *incremetal_upper_bound*, but still concerned if the name could/should somehow reflect that it does increments in exponential way or this is excessive? Both your and my function names suffer from this, I am just curious if this should be exposed by name to the client or not.

Comment: @DamirTenishev I mean that the original code in the question that you rewrote is redundant and only confuses readers of the question. On my opinion it is better to write a new question with your updated code.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I see there you coming from. My question is, is there still a question on the table to open a new one? I got three main answers: there is no such code in standard library, the code had some mistakes, the code is fine for now. Is there a need to distract people with a new question when I got all the answers? What's your point to create a new one? Just to see that there are no answers (very reasonable) for it?

Comment: @DamirTenishev There are no answers except your own. There are only comments. You should show your final code and formulate a question.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, exactly as I guessed, they recommended to post such questions to code review section, since this is the question on working code. So, I posted it there. Could you please revisit and help to improve the [new question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289146/incremental-upper-bound-in-sorted-range), if necessary?